# BIO_do_handshake return 0

Tags: c++, openssl, open-source

I am trying to write a non-blocking connect, when I execute BIO_do_handshake(), using the code below it always returns 0.  I know that you don't necessarily need to 'do_handshake()', but everything seems to appear it it should be done to ensure the handshake completes.

Should I be calling BIO_should_retry()?

```
void SSLAdaptor::Connect( SSL_CTX *ctx
                        , const std::string &hostname
                        , int port
                        , bool nonBlocking )
{

struct hostent *hp;
struct sockaddr_in addr;
SOCKET sockFD;

if( !( hp = gethostbyname( hostname.c_str() ) ) )
{
    return;
}

memset( &addr, 0, sizeof( addr ) );

addr.sin_addr= *( struct in_addr* )hp->h_addr_list[0];
addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
addr.sin_port=htons(port);

if( ( sockFD =socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP ) ) <0 )
{
    return;
}

if(connect(sockFD,(struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr))<0)
{
    return;
}

SSL *ssl;
BIO *sbio;

ssl = SSL_new( ctx );

sbio = BIO_new_socket( sockFD, BIO_NOCLOSE );
SSL_set_bio( ssl, sbio, sbio );

if( SSL_connect( ssl ) <= 0 )
{
     return;
}

long hsReturn = BIO_do_handshake( sbio );

if ( hsReturn <= 0 ) 
{
    return;
}

}
```

My (Non-blocking) BIO read returns rubbish:
Actual : ↨♥   +o     1E¿={û²∙ìφáD'öQñ↨▼≈☺ 
Expected : This is a test message

```
int SSLSocket::BIORead( std::string &buffer, const int size )
{
int bytesRead = -1;
std::vector<char> readBuffer(size);

std::cout << "Before BIO_read() call" << std::endl;
bytesRead = BIO_read( m_bio, readBuffer.data(), size );
std::cout << "After BIO_read() call" << std::endl;
std::cout << "BIO_read() read   : " << bytesRead << " bytes" << std::endl;

std::string tmpBuffer = std::string( readBuffer.begin(), readBuffer.end() );
std::cout << "BIO_read() buffer : " << tmpBuffer << " bytes" << std::endl;

if ( bytesRead < 0 ) 
{
    //  Check if should retry read, if not then an error on the connection
    //  has occurred and the user notified.
    if ( BIO_should_retry( m_bio ) )
    {
        bytesRead = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      // real error
      bytesRead = -1;
  }
}
else if ( bytesRead == 0 ) 
{
    //  Nothing was read
    bytesRead = 0;
}
else
{
    buffer = std::string( readBuffer.begin(), readBuffer.end() );
}

return bytesRead;
}
```

Comment: Added check : if ( BIO_should_retry( sbio ) == false ) and this always returns false

Answer (score 0):

SSL_connect already does the handshake, but you have to use it correctly with a non-blocking socket, e.g. check of SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ, SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE and wait for the required condition as long as SSL_connect returns <0. So there is no need to call BIO_do_handshake.

Comment: sorry, do you mean the WANT_READ/WRITE checks on connect or when using bio_write & bio_read?

Comment: if the socket is non-blocking during SSL_connect you have to use these  checks there too, see documentation https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_connect.html

Comment: Please don't mix SSL and BIO. If you are on SSL use SSL_read, SSL_write, SSL_connect. BIO_read/write on a socket bio will just directly read/write on the socket, e.g. read will get the encrypted data. And please add proper error checking (print out error message) and proper handling of non-blocking case for SSL_connect.